# How to repeatedly sum all digits in a cell until there is only a single digit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm not sure what this operation is called but here are some examples:

4 -> 4

16 -> 1+6 = 7

5765 -> 5+7+6+5 =23 ->2+3 ->5

Comment: Is there an upper limit for the numbers you want to apply the function to?

Comment: @dirdi in theory, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of repeatedly summing the digits of a number is called the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).

Assuming your number is in cell A1, use this formula to calculate the digital root:

```
=IF(A1>0,1+MOD(A1-1,9),0)
```

Here's an example with the formula in cell B1:

[image]

Comment: Awesome formula.  It does break down on larger numbers 13 digits or so, but if that is not an issue, this is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First we want to create an array of numbers starting at 1 an ending at the number of characters:

```
ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))
```

That will return an array of those numbers by creating a range with the number of rows equal to the number of characters.

Then we use MID to parse the data, using the array from the ROW to set the starting point in the string:

```
MID(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),1)
```

This will return an array of the characters: `{"1","6"}`

Then we use SUMPRODUCT to add up the array, with `--` to turn the text into numbers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),1))
```

Then drag that across the columns till you get a single digit.

[image]